# Scrollable Primefaces Datatable Body with fixed paginator bottom

Tags: primefaces

I have primefaces datatable. The paginator is fixed to the bottom of the window. To achieve this I have manipulated the original css selector which you can see below. I would like to achieve that only the table rows are scrolling. The table header and the paginator should stay as they are.

[Datatable View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhU0u.png)

```
                <p:dataTable 
                    id="dtaInternationalization"  
                    binding="#{internationalizationController.dtaHdrLang}"
                    value="#{internationalizationController.itemsHdrLang}" 
                    var="item"
                    widgetVar="widInternationalization" 
                    style="margin-bottom:20px"
                    selectionMode="multiple"
                    liveScroll="true"
                    scrollable="true"
                    scrollHeight="665"
                    selection="#{internationalizationController.selectedItemsHdrLang}"
                    filteredValue="#{internationalizationController.filteredItemsHdrLang}"
                    sortMode="multiple"
                    paginator="true" 
                    paginatorPosition="bottom"
                    paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                    rows="25"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} record(s)"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,75" 
                    rowKey="#{item.pk}"
                    resizableColumns="true" 
                    liveResize="true" 
                    draggableColumns="true">

                    <!-- DATATABLE HEADER SECTION -->
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:toolbar styleClass="fw-panel-title-header">
                            <p:toolbarGroup styleClass="fw-toolbar-group-left">
                                <p:outputLabel id="lblPageTitle"
                                    value="Edit Datatable Settings" styleClass="fw-title-bar" />
                            </p:toolbarGroup>
                            <p:toolbarGroup styleClass="fw-toolbar-group-right">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Global Search:  "
                                    styleClass="fw-global-search" />
                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                    onkeyup="PF('widTableView').filter()" style="width:250px"
                                    placeholder="Enter Keyword" />
                            </p:toolbarGroup>
                            <p:toolbarGroup styleClass="fw-toolbar-group-right">
                                <p:commandButton id="cbProperties" icon="fa fa-gear" title="View Settings" />
                                <p:commandButton id="refreshButton" value="Refresh"
                                    icon="fa fa-refresh"
                                    actionListener="#{internationalizationController.refresh}"
                                    update="dtaInternationalization" />
                                <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Add" icon="fa fa-plus"
                                    actionListener="#{internationalizationController.addLanguage}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('widAddLanguage').show()" />
                                <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" value="Delete"
                                    icon="fa fa-remove"
                                    disabled="#{empty internationalizationController.selectedItemsHdrLang}" />
                            </p:toolbarGroup>
                            <p:toolbarGroup styleClass="fw-toolbar-group-right">
                                <p:ajaxStatus
                                    style="width:20px;height:20px;position:relative;margin-right:15px;">
                                    <f:facet name="start">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin ajax-loader"
                                            aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="complete">
                                        <h:outputText value="" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:ajaxStatus>
                            </p:toolbarGroup>
                            <p:toolbarGroup styleClass="fw-toolbar-group-right"
                                style="margin-right:15px">
                                <p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="true" closable="false" styleClass="fw-messages-title-bar" showSummary="false" showIcon="false" /> 
                            </p:toolbarGroup>
                        </p:toolbar>
                    </f:facet>

                    <!-- DATATABLE COLUMN SECTION -->
                    <p:column headerText="Image" styleClass="center" width="50">
                        <o:graphicImage value="#{item.flagImageSmall}" dataURI="true"
                            rendered="#{!empty item.flagImageSmall}" />

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Default" styleClass="center"
                        filterBy="#{item.languageDefault}" filterMatchMode="equals"
                        sortBy="#{item.languageDefault}" width="110">
                        <f:facet name="filter">
                            <p:selectOneButton
                                onchange="PF('widInternationalization').filter()"
                                styleClass="custom-filter">
                                <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" />
                            </p:selectOneButton>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{item.languageDefault}">
                            <i class="fa fa-check" />
                        </p:outputLabel>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Active" styleClass="center"
                        filterBy="#{item.activeFlag}" filterMatchMode="equals"
                        sortBy="#{item.activeFlag}" width="110">
                        <f:facet name="filter">
                            <p:selectOneButton
                                onchange="PF('widInternationalization').filter()"
                                styleClass="custom-filter">
                                <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" />
                            </p:selectOneButton>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{item.activeFlag}">
                            <i class="fa fa-check" />
                        </p:outputLabel>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Code" styleClass="center" width="90"
                        filterBy="#{item.languageCode}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                        sortBy="#{item.languageCode}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.languageCode}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Language" filterBy="#{item.languageName}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{item.languageName}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.languageName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Created" filterBy="#{item.createDate}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{item.createDate}" width="6%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.createDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime 
                                locale="#{parameterSessionController.localeCode}" type="localDateTime"
                                dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="medium" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Created by" filterBy="#{item.createUser}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{item.createUser}" width="6%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.createUser}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Modified" filterBy="#{item.modifyDate}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{item.modifyDate}" width="6%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.modifyDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime
                                locale="#{parameterSessionController.localeCode}" type="localDateTime"
                                dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="medium" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Modfied by" filterBy="#{item.modifyUser}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{item.modifyUser}" width="6%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.modifyUser}" />
                    </p:column>


                    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
                        listener="#{internationalizationController.editLanguage}"
                        oncomplete="PF('widLanguage').show()" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="deleteButton" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="deleteButton" />
                </p:dataTable>
```

The paginator css selectorI have manipulated as follow:

```
body .ui-datatable .ui-paginator {
padding: 6px 12px;
border-style: none;
border-top: solid 2px #9fd037;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: -webkit-fill-available;
z-index: 1;
```

}

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you specify which pf version are you using and if you're using any theme?

Comment: I'm using PrimeFaces 8

Comment: I was finding a way to make the table scrollable as expect. I only need to know how I can adjust the height of the class "ui-datatable-scrollable-body" programmatically maybe with jQuery based on the height of the window? Thank you Christian

Comment: Have you tried adding some style to class `ui-datatable-scrollable-body`? For example, if your header and your footer are both 50px height, you could try adding something like this: `max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);` (try some variants, min / max / height) to ui-datatable-scrollable-body class (or try a more specific selector)

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea to solve it just with plain css. Meanwhile I was finding a way doing it with jQuery. I'm going to set the height of ui-datatable-scrollable-body by deducting all outerheights of the visible container from the window height. I'm doing it when resize is triggered, the document is ready or the paginator is changing the rows per page. In addition I'm adding a margin-right to the datatable header if the scrollbar is visible reset the margin if the scrollbar get back invisible.